# Custom api in sugarcrm 8.0

Tags: php, rest, api, sugarcrm

The function of my code is, i want it to capitalize the initial letters of the field firstname and last name when they click the Upper name button.

here's the code:

```
<?php

class UpperNameApi extends SugarApi
{
    public function registerApiRest()
    {
        return array(
            'UpperNameRequest' => array(
                //request type
                'reqType' => 'GET',

                //endpoint path
                'path' => array('Leads', 'UpperName'),

                //endpoint variables
                'pathVars' => array('module','record'),

                //method to call
                'method' => 'UpperNameMethod',

                //short help string to be displayed in the help documentation
                'shortHelp' => 'Example endpoint',

                //long help to be displayed in the help documentation
                'longHelp' => 'custom/clients/base/api/help/MyEndPoint_MyGetEndPoint_help.html',
            ),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Method to be used for my MyEndpoint/GetExample endpoint
     */
    public function UpperNameMethod($api, $args)
    {
        if (isset($args['record']) && !empty($args['record'])) {
            $bean = BeanFactory::getBean('Leads', $args['record']);

            if (!empty($bean->id)) {
                $first = $bean->first_name;
                $first = ucwords($first);
                $bean->first_name = $first;

                $last = $bean->last_name;
                $last = ucwords($last);
                $bean->last_name = $last;
                $bean->save();
            }

            return 'success';
        }


        return 'failed';

    }

}
```

When i click the "Upper name button" it doesn't work:

[image: When i click the "Upper name button" it doesn't work:]

i also tried using postman but this showed up: "error_message": "Could not find a route with 3 elements"

[image: pic2]

## UPDATED

ive made another request in postman with this values but it shows: "A parameter in your request was invalid."

[image: pic3]

## UPDATED AGAIN

PROBLEM FIXED.

Comment: Please add an answer and share what the solution was :)
If the problem was nothing that interesting to begin with (e.g. a random typo), maybe consider deleting the question.

Comment: oh sorry bout that. i'll add the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this one was really simple and yet it took me hours to figure out. anyways the answer is the `'reqType' => 'GET'` line should be `'reqType' => 'POST'`.

Comment: cool :) Also I'd suggest you accept your answer as solution so that people can see that this question has a solution when browsing through the questions. (Am I'm annoying you yet? :D)

Comment: Its fine bro :D although i dont know how to do that yet xD

Comment: You already accepted an answer (on that other question, my answer), so you should already know how to accept answers? xD

Comment: Haha yep i just recently found out. Tsk xD